# updating all elments in an array

Tags: immutable.js

I have to update all the elements in an array using Immutablejs

The JSON looks like this :

```
imState = Immutable.fromJS({
  app: {
    line: {
      name: "Bar Chart",
      series: [
        {
          name: "Series1x",
          color: "#82ca9d"
        },
        {
          name: "Series2x",
          color: "#2239ca"
        },
        {
          name: "Series3x",
          color: "#c2a5ca"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

And I would simply like to iterate over all the series elements and change the color to a fixed color "#1bf115".

I am guessing you would use the **update** function. There is no API documentation on this function so I have been doing a lot of trial an error.

I tried to use it like this :

```
imState = imState.update(
  ['app', 'line', 'series'],
  series => series.map(s => s.update('color', color => "#1bf115"))
)
```

However I get an undefined error at **series.map**.

Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are supplying a deeply nested path , instead of `update` use `updateIn`.

```
imState = imState.updateIn(
  ['app', 'line', 'series'],
  series => series.map(s => s.update('color', color => "#1bf115"))
)
```